# A nonlinear ordinary differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the ordinary differential equation $$y'=y(y-1)(y-2)$$ Then which of the following statements is true?
>
> 1)If $y(0)=0.5$ then $y$ is decreasing
>
> 2) If $y(0)=1.2$ then $y$ is increasing
>
> 3) If $y(0)=2.5$ then $y$ is unbounded
>
> 4) If $y(0)<0$ then $y$ is bounded below

Using partial fractions I get

$$\big( \dfrac{1}{2y} -\dfrac{1}{y-1}+\dfrac{1}{2(y-2)}\big)dy=dx$$ which upon integration gives  $$ \dfrac{y(y-2)}{(y-1)^{2}}=C e^{2x}$$

Can anyone help me how to rule out the options?

Comment: May helps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843817